# Lighttpd/FastCGI treating routes as static content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fastcgi, lighttpd

I've come across a frustrating issue with FastCGI and Rails whereby lighttpd is treating routed url's as static files (i.e. not sending them to rails since it believes they're static)

If I hit the root path I get the rails application, but as soon as I hit something with a URL structure, even a path that matches the default :controller/:action route, I get a 404 from lighttpd and the rails app isn't even consulted.

Here's my lighttpd.conf:

```
server.modules = ( "mod_rewrite", "mod_redirect", "mod_access", "mod_status", "mod_fastcgi", "mod_accesslog" )

server.document-root = "/myapp/application/public"
index-file.names = ( "index.html", "dispatch.fcgi" )
server.error-handler-404 = "/myapp/application/public/404.html"

url.access-deny = ( "~", ".inc" )
server.pid-file = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username = "lighttpd"
server.groupname = "lighttpd"

server.errorlog = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"

#### fastcgi module
fastcgi.server = (
    ".fcgi" => (
        "myapp" => (
            "socket" => "/tmp/myapp.socket",
            "bin-path" => "/myapp/application/public/dispatch.fcgi",
            "check-local" => "disable",
            "fix-root-scriptname" => "true",
            "docroot"=>"/"
        )
    )
)

# mimetype mapping
mimetype.assign = (...)
```

As for errors, I don't get any at all.
Although, if I turn on debugging in Lighttpd, I do see events like these:

```
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.261) URI-path     :  /tracking/index 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.375) -- before doc_root 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.376) Doc-Root     : /myapp/application/tracking/public 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.377) Rel-Path     : /tracking/index 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.378) Path         :  
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.426) -- after doc_root 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.427) Doc-Root     : /myapp/application/tracking/public 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.428) Rel-Path     : /tracking/index 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.429) Path         : /myapp/application/tracking/public/tracking/index 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.446) -- logical -> physical 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.447) Doc-Root     : /myapp/application/tracking/public 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.448) Rel-Path     : /tracking/index 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.449) Path         : /myapp/application/tracking/public/tracking/index 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.466) -- handling physical path 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.467) Path         : /myapp/application/tracking/public/tracking/index 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.523) -- file not found 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.524) Path         : /myapp/application/tracking/public/tracking/index 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.205) -- splitting Request-URI 
2010-01-18 23:11:18: (response.c.206) Request-URI  :  /myapp/application/tracking/public/404.html
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a facepalm moment there although the documentation doesn't really explain the importance of the server.error-handler setting.

When using fcgi, you need to ensure your error-handler is set to redirect to the fcgi dispatch, else, it'll just show a 404 page.

```
server.error-handler-404 = "/dispatch.fcgi"
```

All fixed now.

Comment: Note that when using "server.error-handler-N" you treat error pages as fully qualified requests. They return code "200" to all requests. To actually be able to return pages with error codes by correct value you should use "server.errorfile-prefix", where you declare a folder with html files with the error numbers as file names (i.e. "404.html").